# Реализация алгоритмов, работающих с данными, в модели MVC (spring, java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, дерево, graph

При реализации web приложения возник вопрос, каким образом, точнее, где именно в MVC, должна быть реализована логика обработки выгруженных из базы данных. То есть, понятно, что работа с базой определяется с помощью entities в модели, контроллер осуществляет связь модели и представления. Но требуется данные не просто отдать, обновить или удалить, но и определить для них структуру, например, собрать граф. С точки зрения верной архитектуры приложения, правильной организации слоев или других best practics, где должен быть реализован алгоритм сбора графа после выгрузки данных из базы?
В настоящий момент, структура проекта следующая:

```
project
   |__ model (entity)
   |__ repository
   |__ service
   |__ restcontroller
```

Comment: Если "сборка графа" относится к прикладной логике, то располагаться она должна в сервисном слое. Если это просто промежуточная конвертация данных, то может располагаться в репозитории.

Comment: Это относится к прикладной логике, кроме того, граф предполагается обходить, применяя различные условия поиска

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в SERVICE потому как это бизнес логика приложения,
в repository вы достаете даные из бд и отдаете в service
в service обрабатываете как вам угодно и передаете restcontroller